How to get EC2 Proxy object using AWS CDK
I want to get the Proxy object of an EC2 so that I can add some tags to it. But I am not able to find any direct method to get a EC2 instance using its ID or anything related to it in cdk.
Versions:
CDK: v2
Runtime: NodeJS + Typescript

You're right, there doesn't seem to be any static method for importing an EC2 instance but even if there was, you wouldn't be able to attach tags to it through a proxy object.

When you create such a proxy, the external resource does not become a part of your AWS CDK app. Therefore, changes you make to the proxy in your AWS CDK app do not affect the deployed resource. The proxy can, however, be passed to any AWS CDK method that requires a resource of that type.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html#resources_referencing
If you created the EC2 instance manually, you could import it to your CDK application using cdk import.
